# why superscript not displaying in pdf from r-markdown using kable extra?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to read superscript by notation using excel. it is displaying in the chunk but while generating in pdf superscript is not getting displayed.

I'm reading excel file like this as shown below

```
Col
-----
word${^1}$
word${^1}$
word${^1}$
word${^1}$
word${^1}$
word${^1}$

dput(head(df))
structure(list(Col = c("word${^1}$", "word${^1}$", "word${^1}$", 
"word${^1}$", "word${^1}$", "word${^1}$")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
df<-read_excel("../suprscript.xlsx", sheet = 'sheet1')

kbl(df,longtable = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position","repeat_header"),full_width = F)
```

superscript getting displayed on running a chunk in markdown but in pdf its showing as

```
word${^1}$
```

Comment: Superscript of what?

Comment: superscript for text  like ```word$^1$ ``` 1 is superscript of word. the way i represent in excel superscript is getting displayed in markdown chunk but not displaying in pdf. Superscript to be inside table display using kable

Comment: Please run `dput(head(df))` and paste the result into the question. I do not have the time or inclination to transcribe an image into a variable. Please use `dput` because pasting a text table still requires effort to parse. If you use dput, it is guaranteed to be the same in your environment and in anyone trying to fix your problem.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm I have pasted the output of ```dput(head(df))```

Comment: Right - and `escape = F` fixes  the problem - I updated my answer to match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `escape=F` option when calling `kableExtra::kbl` like the following `.Rmd` file.

````
---
title: "Mathematical symbols in tables"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
df <- structure(list(Col = c("word${^1}$", "word${^1}$", 
"word${^1}$", 
"word${^1}$", "word${^1}$", "word${^1}$")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
result <- 
    kbl(df,longtable = T, escape=F) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = 
        c("hold_position","repeat_header"),full_width = F)
result
```
````

Here's a screenshot from the resulting PDF.

[image]

Comment: using  escape=F ```Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete.``` i'm getting this error. if i remove escape=F in pdf its displaying as same ```${^1}$``` like this. I'm reading this from excel. In chunk it's getting displayed but not in pdf

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example otherwise we will just be guessing. I suggest you post your markdown and do `dput` on the Excel data and paste that into the original question.